# C++ ofstream not able to write if open() is in another class method

Tags: c++, scope, ofstream

I have a class FileTransfer that uses an ofstream object, log. The class' constructor calls open() on the ofstream object, with logFileName having a default value in the .h file.

```
class FileTransfer {
    public:
        FileTransfer(char *logFileName = "client log.txt");
        bool sendFile();
        ofstream log;           // log file
};

FileTransfer::FileTransfer(char * logFileName) {
    this -> logFileName = logFileName;
    // Open log file
    log.open(logFileName);
}
```

In another class method, sendFile(), I use the stream to log events.

```
bool FileTransfer::sendFile() {
    log << "Sender: starting on host " << localhost << endl;
}
```

When I have it like this, nothing is written to the log file . I've tried checking log.is_open() and good() and both return true.

**EDIT:**

```
int main() {
    FileTransfer * ft = new FileTransfer(); // open() is called
    ft -> sendFile(); 
}
```

If I call log.open() in the method FileTransfer::sendFile() right before my output operations, then output works perfectly fine.

```
bool FileTransfer::sendFile() {
    log.open(logFileName);
    log << "Sender: starting on host " << localhost << endl;
}
```

Why does it do this?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal test-case?  (see http://sscce.org)

Comment: It shoudn't be like you say. Remove `if(TRACE)` it is irrelevant for your question if you are correct and still it is always better to narrow the cause of problems. Also please add the trial code of calling `log.open()` in `sendFile`.

Comment: Where is `log` declared and as what? Is it possible that you have multiple names `log` around and different ones are used? Based on what you posted there is no reason why there should be any issue.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't obvious: "I have a class FileTransfer that uses an ofstream object". I added it to the class definition so it is clearer. There is only one `log` entity.

Comment: Hmm I tried out your code and it works for me as you expect it (even though I had to declare `log`, `localhost` and `logFileName` and had to add return statement in the `sendFile` method.

Comment: The weird thing is it worked last night. I left my computer open overnight. I come back to test and now it doesn't. (There is a return statement in my code, I just haven't shown it here, for simplicity's sake.) I'll just put the open() in the sendFile() method and stop breaking my head.

Comment: It is working for me too when I compile the code above. I guess that maybe the comment above about you have multiple instances with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha I know what is you problem! You are writing to the file, but actually it goes to a buffer and is not flushed in the first case (this is a bit random).

Add the following line after your printing:

```
log.flush();
```

It should fix your issue.

Comment: I have that in the destructor and at the end of the sendFile() method. It doesn't do anything. 'endl' actually does a flush operation on the stream, so that isn't it. Also, why would that change the fact that writing works if the open() is in the sendFile() method?

Comment: Well as I already mentioned flushing is a bit random and might happen out of very weird reasons. I am sorry my suggestion did not work. I will leave it out though. Hopefully it will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Note that `std::endl` already include a call to the stream's `flush()` method: flushing again should not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Should the constructor for FileTransfer look like this instead.

```
FileTransfer::FileTransfer(char * logFileName) : log( logFileName ) {
}
```

That way the ofstream is constructed in the correct way. And no need to call open(). I also think that is better design for handling errors and creation of objects.